# Python - Argument of type 'function' is not iterable error

Tags: python-2.7

So I'm supposed to write some code that takes in some lines of text, reworks them by removing all non-key words, punctuation, etc. and finally prints each keyword and which lines it appears on. At one point my code was working then, seemingly without changing anything I started getting this error and I have no idea why. I'm not looking for ways to make the code shorter or anything, I realise it's far from ideal. I would just like to know how to fix this error.

EDIT- Error is on line 58, in createindex if  word not in index:

Here is the code:

```
from string import *

# Program to index sentences

stopWords = [ "a", "i", "it", "am", "at", "on", "in", "to", "too", "very", \
              "of", "from", "here", "even", "the", "but", "and", "is", "my", \
              "them", "then", "this", "that", "than", "though", "so", "are" ]

punctuation = [".",",",":",";","!","?","&","'"]
stemming=["s","es","ed","er","ly","ing"]
text={}
reworkedtext={}

def inserttext(text):    #Function to insert lines of text
    linecount=1
    print "Please insert text here:"
    line = ""
    while line!=".":
        line = raw_input()
        text[linecount]=line
        linecount+=1

def reworktext(text):   #Reworks the text by removing punctuation and making everything lowercase
    for line in text:
        reworkedtext[line]=""
        for character in range(0,len(text[line])):
            if text[line][character] not in punctuation:
                reworkedtext[line]=reworkedtext[line]+lower(text[line][character])

def removestopwords(reworkedtext):   #Removes stopwords
    for line in reworkedtext:
        wordcount=0
        reworkedtext[line]=split(reworkedtext[line])
        for word in range(0,len(reworkedtext[line])):
            if reworkedtext[line][wordcount] in stopWords:
                del(reworkedtext[line][wordcount])
            else:
                wordcount+=1

def stemwords(reworkedtext):  #Stems all words
    for line in reworkedtext:
        for word in range(0,len(reworkedtext[line])):
            if reworkedtext[line][word][-2:] in stemming:
                reworkedtext[line][word]=reworkedtext[line][word][:-2]
            if reworkedtext[line][word][-3:] in stemming:
                reworkedtext[line][word]=reworkedtext[line][word][:-3]
            if reworkedtext[line][word][-1:] in stemming:
                reworkedtext[line][word]=reworkedtext[line][word][:-1]

def createindex(reworkedtext): #creates index and prints it
    linecount=1
    for line in reworkedtext:
        for word in range(0,len(reworkedtext[line])):
            if  word not in index:
                index[word]=""
                index[word]=str(line)
                linecount+=1
            elif index[word]!=str(line):
                index[word]=index[word]+", "+str(line)
    for words in index:
        print words, index[words]

inserttext(text)

reworktext(text)

removestopwords(reworkedtext)

stemwords(reworkedtext)

createindex(reworkedtext)
```

Comment: Seriously? You're not even going to tell us which line it's on?

Comment: Crap, sorry! It's  
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\indexer.py", line 75, in <module>
    createindex(reworkedtext)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\indexer.py", line 58, in createindex
    if  word not in index:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you forgot to initialze your index dictionary

```
def createindex(reworkedtext): #creates index and prints it
    linecount=1
    index = {} # <----------- add this line and see what's what :)
    for line in reworkedtext:
        for word in range(0,len(reworkedtext[line])):
            if  word not in index:
                index[word]=""
                index[word]=str(line)
                linecount+=1
            elif index[word]!=str(line):
                index[word]=index[word]+", "+str(line)
    for words in index:
        print words, index[words]
```

Comment: Yep, that's it. I must have accidentally deleted it when I was removing some test code, but with such an error code the thought would have never even crossed my mind! Thanks!